# How to escape brackets in a multi-line string in Lua

Tags: lua

This is an exercise question from the book the lua programming language the 3th edition.

Exercise2.4: How can you embed the following piece of XML as a string in Lua?

Show at least two different ways.

Here is my answer:

```
 s = "<![CDATA\n  Hello world\n]]>"
 print(s)

 s2 = [[
 <![CDATA
    Hello world
  \]\]>
 ]]
 print(s2)
```

and the output:

```
<![CDATA
 Hello world
]]>
<![CDATA
 Hello world
\]\]>
```

Way 1 is right. The output of way 2 is not as expected. Without the backslash char, lua will show an error:

```
 lua: execrcise-4.1.lua:7: unexpected symbol near ']'
```

So I have a question, how to escape brackets in a multi-line string in Lua ?

My lua interpreter version is 5.4.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the whole point of this exercise is that you find out how to solve this problem.

Ideally by reading the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1).

There you'll learn that opening and closing brackets for long strings have levels.

> Literal strings can also be defined using a long format enclosed by
> long brackets. We define an opening long bracket of level n as an
> opening square bracket followed by n equal signs followed by another
> opening square bracket. So, an opening long bracket of level 0 is
> written as [[, an opening long bracket of level 1 is written as [=[,
> and so on. A closing long bracket is defined similarly; for instance,
> a closing long bracket of level 4 is written as ]====]. A long literal
> starts with an opening long bracket of any level and ends at the first
> closing long bracket of the same level. **It can contain any text except
> a closing bracket of the same level.**

```
s2 = [[
 <![CDATA
    Hello world
  ]]>
 ]]
```

violates that bold rule as you close the long string prematurely leaving you with two extra brackets that cause a syntax error.

So what do you need to do if the string may not contain a closing bracket of level 0 `]]` ? We increase the level of our long string.

```
s2 = [=[
 <![CDATA
    Hello world
  ]]>
 ]=]
```

You cannot escape a square bracket with a backslash in a Lua string btw.
The only reason why you didn't get an error for the invalid escape sequence `\]` is that long strings ignore escape sequences.

Comment: It solves my problem, thanks. I read the manual and realize that the text after the opening bracket "[[" can not contains the closing bracket "]]". That's why we need the equal sign to increase the level.